# Ingresar X y Y de manera simultanea

Tags: c++, array

Necesito realizar un programa donde pueda insertar datos tipo puntos (x,y), quisiera saber si hay forma de introducirlos de manera simultanea separados por comas en lugar de en dos ciclos for distintos.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int cant,n;
    float x[101],y[101], xint,yinterpol=0, num, denom;

    cout<<"Cantidad de Puntos:" ;
    cin>>cant;
    cout<<"Ingrese los valores (x):";

    for(int i=1;i<=cant;i++){
        cin>>x[i];  

    }
    cout<<"Ingrese los valores (y):";

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cin>>y[i];  

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si la hay, tu debes programarla. Puedes, por ejemplo, pedir una cadena de texto en el formato que te interese y luego vas extrayendo los números de esta cadena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si suponemos una entrada tal que `3,4` se podría hacer algo así:

```
char c;
std::cin >> x[i] >> c >> y[i];
```

Luego ya quedaría en tu mano verificar que `c` sea efectivamente una coma y no otra cosa, como una letra.

Aunque no es para nada necesario usar una coma. Los espacios, tabuladores y saltos de línea son considerados como separadores en C++. Este detalle es importante, ya que el operador de extracción `>>` de `cin` **elimina** estos separadores.

Así, la siguiente línea:

```
std::cin >> x[i] >> y[i];
```

Leerá perfectamente dos enteros bajo diferentes situaciones:

- Separados por espacios

  ```
  3 4
  3                  4
  ```
- Separados por saltos de línea

  ```
  3
  4
  ```
- Separados por tabuladores
- Combinación cualquiera de distintos separadores

Así que, como vés, no hay ninguna necesidad de complicarle la vida ni al usuario ni al programador.